# Delayed Alamofire Request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

We are making an API call using Alamofire and want it to be asynchronous but delayed by 2 seconds. We are using this to delay the call but I THINK this might be causing something to run on the main thread. What is the best way to wait 2 seconds to run a request like this?

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
     //This is the Alamofire API call
     self.excecuteGetRequest(id, product: product)
}
```

Here is something else that I tried but I am not sure if it is right.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {

     let qualityOfServiceClass = DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated
     let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: qualityOfServiceClass)
     backgroundQueue.async(execute: {
          self.excecuteGetRequest(cartID, product: product)
     })
}
```

Here is the request if that helps:

```
func excecuteGetRequest(_ id:String,product:Product) {
    let url = "www.api.sampleAPI.com/random"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (innerResponse) in
        print("Inner response = \(innerResponse)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use main queue, try using the `DispatchQueue.global`

Comment: It turns out that I was mistaken and this was not being run on the main thread but thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
let requestQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "alamofire.queue")
requestQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2.0) {
    //Do your Alamofire request here
    //After it complete his task return response in main queue if needed
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //you can return response like this
    }
}
```